# Phonegap camera doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

My Android app need to takes picture but Camera plugin doesn't work. When I click on the button nothing happens.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
      function onDeviceReady() {              
          alert("ready");
        }
    function capturePhoto()
    {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 
    }

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = imageURI;
    }

    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }    

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto()">Capture</button> <br>
    <button onclick="onDeviceReady()">alert</button> <br>
    <img id="myImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I added second button only to check if button works(and it does).

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap= "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id= "testaplikacji"
        versionCode= "1"
        version = "1.0.0" >
    <name>Camera</name>
    <description>Camera test</description>
    <author>Sebastian</author>
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" /> 
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />

    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>


    <access origin="*"/>
    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="add" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    </gap:config-file>

</widget>
```

I tried with and without permissions. I tried different plugins. I tried with this gist: https://gist.github.com/dhavaln/2238017

And also code from this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlBfmHDZjmg

Nothing works. I waste a lot of time trying to make this works. Please help me.

Comment: Do you see the "ready" message when starting your app. (Without clicking on the alert button)?

Comment: Yes, works every time.

Comment: Try to use `adb logcat` to see whether there are any meaningful hints or warnings output while running the app.

Comment: When I clicked on "capture" button I got this: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(15)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined", source: file:///data/data/.../files/downloads/app_dir/index.html (15)

Comment: index.html line 15 is navigator.camera.getPicture... in capturePhoto() function. So now I know where is the problem. Thank you for suggesting using logcat. But I don't know why this error occurs. Do you have some ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you use the phonegap cloud buid service or build the app on your own computer?

Comment: I use phonegap cloud build service. And according to this service I've got installed "cordova-plugin-camera"  pgb 1.2.0, "org.apache.cordova.camera"    pgb 0.3.6 and "org.apache.cordova.dialogs"    pgb 0.3.0. Could this problem be caused by having two camera plugins?

Comment: When `navigator.camera` is still undefined even after you have received the `deviceready` notification, this means that the camera plugin is not there or not working properly.

Comment: So is there any possible solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this with the phonegap build server and the HTML code you supplied works (with the change from my other answer) when using this minimal `config.xml` file with your html file. Also, be sure not to upload the `phonegap.js` in the Zip archive to the build server. An extra one will be added automatically during the build.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.stackoverflow.example.SO37227132"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>PhoneGap Example</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build docs. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        Hardeep Shoker 
    </author>

    <platform name="android" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="pgb" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a variable named image at two different places. But these are two different variables. Get the image reference where you need it in the onSuccess function.

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) 
{
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = imageURI;
}
```

Comment: I changed this but it didn't help. Still doesn't work.